# Devise: change params in registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to change parameter before it saves in model object in `create` action of Devise `registrations_controller`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  def create
    phone = params[:user][:phone]
    replacements = [ [' ', ''], ['-', ''], ['(', ''], [')', ''], ['+', ''] ]
    params[:user][:phone] = replacements.each { |replacement| phone.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1]) }
    super
  end

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(:name, :surname, :patronymic, :username, :phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
        u.permit(:name, :surname, :patronymic, :username, :phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
      end
    end

end
```

The problem is I can't change `params[:user][:phone]` because it unpermitted: `Unpermitted parameters: phone`. How can I change it after I get params? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These aren't permitted because of Rails Strong Parameters. See the 'Strong Parameters' section in the [Devise Github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Long story short, something like this should be placed into your ApplicationController, not the Devise controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :phone
  end
end
```

Comment: there is the same result